# Extracting file names from text using regular expression Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to extract source code file names saved in python string variable. However, variable contains html type tags and lot of other contents as shown below:

```
<p> Result = FAILURE<br/ hshreedharan : <a href="http://git-wip-
<ul>
<li>flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/HDFSEventSink.java</li>     
<li>flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/test/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/TestBucketWriter.java</li>
<li>flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/BucketWriter.java</li>
<li>sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/BucketWriter.java</li>
<li>sink.src.main.java.org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.java</li>          
</ul>
```

However, I am looking for proper regular expression using "re" python library to ignore all other text, html tags and extract output only as source code files contained in the variable.

```
flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/HDFSEventSink.java
flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/test/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/TestBucketWriter.java
flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/BucketWriter.java
sink.src.main.java.org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.java
sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/BucketWriter.java
```

Currently, I am using following code:

```
  import re

  htmlText= \\ may be variable containing above code

  matchSrcFiles= re.findall('\\.[^.]*.java$', htmlText) \\text ending .java
```

Help for proper regular expression or function modification like, re.sub to extract relavent source code files shall be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use re.sub? Do you want to match and replace the pattern with some other pattern?

Comment: Actually, I only need to extract source code file. Asking, if re.sub or re.findall is effective.

Comment: re.findall() does the job. re.sub() is used for substitution.

Comment: I also edited the question, but, it does not produce required output with your regular expression. Can we add multiple regular expression into variable and then use re.findall ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:  `([a-zA-Z-.\/]+.java)`

```
import re

a="""<p> Result = FAILURE<br/ hshreedharan : <a href="http://git-wip-
<ul>
<li>flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/HDFSEventSink.java</li>     
<li>flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/test/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/TestBucketWriter.java</li>
<li>flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/BucketWriter.java</li>
</ul>
channel/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/channel/file/protoProtosFactory.java.
sink.src.main.java.apache.flume.sink.java
"""

pat = "([a-zA-Z-.\/]+.java)"
c =  re.findall(pat,a)
print c
```

output:

```
['flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/HDFSEventSink.java', 'flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/test/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/TestBucketWriter.java', 'flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/BucketWriter.java', 'channel/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/channel/file/protoProtosFactory.java', 'sink.src.main.java.apache.flume.sink.java']
```

Demo on Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/zzFpKJ/3

Comment: Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi, can you kindly share your email address for further help. Thanks

Comment: If it solved your problem, then consider accepting the answer :) Click on the tick mark on the left of the answer.

Comment: You can find me on LinkedIn with the same name. I have mentioned my email address there.

Comment: Actually, not qualified to tick vote mark :(. Surely, will get it done by my colleagues. Thanks!. Can you rather inbox you email?

Comment: You don't need any reputation to accept the answer. Click on the tick mark, which is kind of transparent below the like and dislike buttons.

Comment: When I click it says, reputation Votes casts less than reputation 15 are not recorded. Between How about extracting files having following patterns:            
   1.channel/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/channel/file/proto/ProtosFactory.java.
2.sink.src.main.java.apache.flume.sink.java

Comment: I realize, I rather need regular expression for source files appearing with different patterens

Comment: You don't click on the small triangles for accepting the answer. You click on tick mark '✔'. Please update your question. I'll try to provide you with the solution if I can.

Comment: I have updated the regex. Now it will match these two patterns also channel/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/channel/file/proto/‌​ProtosFactory.java and sink.src.main.java.apache.flume.sink.java

Comment: Yes licked the tick mark now. By the way, updated regular expression does not work still properly. Probably, first it check for alphabatic following "-" and then look for ".", however required one is either of them or excluding either of them.

Comment: I am sorry, I cross checked it. It works perfectly fine. Thanks!